# jQuery disable preventDefault

Tags: jquery

I need to disble `event.preventDefault()` after an amount of time (in e.g. 5s). Right now i have the next code:

```js
var isDblclick = false;
event.preventDefault();
setTimeout(function() {
        if(!isDblclick) {
                // Disable prevent default (Wishing to click again)
        }
}, 5000);
isDblclick = true;
```

How can I get the expected result?

**EDIT:** After David's comment, I am posting the full code here:

```js
var isDblclick = false;
$('.block-header-wrapper ul.nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
                if(!isDblclick) {
                        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(10).fadeIn(400);
                }
        }, 500);
});

$('.block-header-wrapper ul.nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu').on('dblclick', function() {
        isDblclick = true;

        // On double click, anchor tag could be clicked

        isDblclick = false;
});
```

Comment: Once prevented, you cannot undo the prevention. Other than that, it is completely unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to take a step back here.  What event are you preventing, and what do you want to happen after 5 seconds?  "disable preventDefault" doesn't make a lot of sense, but maybe after 5 seconds you want to manually raise the original event?  Perhaps you could provide a more complete example of your intended goal?

Comment: @David It is just a jQuery to prevent the click when this is once clicked, but when it is double clicked I would want to click again. If I do the preventDefault, I can't click again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close but you should use a variable to store the state like this instead.

```js
let clicked = false;

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log(clicked);
  if(!clicked) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      clicked = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
  clicked = true;    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a extra variable to controle the time to `event.preventDefault()`.

```
var preDefault = false;
setTimeout(function() {
       preDefault = true;         
        }, 5000);

$('.block-header-wrapper ul.nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu').on('click', function() {
        if(preDefault)
             event.preventDefault();
});
```